# Configure Facebook share dialog to show the default as "Friends' Timeline"

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

To open a regular share dialog like this one:

[image]

I use this following code:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://www.happymood.co',
}, function(response){});
```

Now if I want the default option to show "On your **Friends' Timeline**" instead of "On your own Timeline", what changes must I make to this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s not possible at all to define another default setting. You can check out the Facebook docs to see what parameters you can use: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: So the only way one can make it easy to share a story on a friends' timeline is via a back-end integration with the Graph API?

Comment: that´s not possible either, you can´t post on the friends wall with the graph api - luckily, because it would most likely be spam. just don´t preselect the option.

Comment: What about this? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2 It says you can specify a to and from parameter.

Comment: And don't you think that the Send Dialog is a better option for my use case?

Comment: the feed dialog does not post on the wall of a friend, and you would need to have the id for the to parameter. does not work for non app users, for example. and the send dialog sends a private message.