# How to set the default of Facebook dropdown box when sharing to "Share on a friend's Timeline"

Tags: facebook

I want to send an email.  Inside of the email will be a link to share on facebook.  However, instead of defaulting to share "On your own Timeline" I'd like it to default to "On a friend's Timeline'.  Is this possible.

What setting do I need to change to make that drop down box default to "On a friend's Timeline"?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a real programming question.  Do you have code for what you're trying to do?

Comment: It's definitely not a Facebook setting.  It's something that needs to be done with the Javascript SDK or through the Facebook Feed or Share Dialog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure Facebook share dalog to show the default as "Friends' Timeline"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874019/configure-facebook-share-dalog-to-show-the-default-as-friends-timeline)

Answer (score 0):

Disregard.  I found this duplicate question and solution after posting.

[Configure Facebook share dalog to show the default as "Friends' Timeline"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874019/configure-facebook-share-dalog-to-show-the-default-as-friends-timeline)